# Querying to show all rows with a max value SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing a query to count how many students each staff member supervises

```
SELECT   FACULTY.F_FIRST || ' ' || F_LAST AS STAFF,(COUNT(FACULTY.F_FIRST || ' ' || F_LAST)) as STUDENTCOUNT
FROM STUDENT

INNER JOIN FACULTY 
ON STUDENT.F_ID=FACULTY.F_ID


GROUP BY FACULTY.F_FIRST,FACULTY.F_LAST
;
```

which correctly outputs

```
Teresa Marx 3
Colin Langley   1
Jonnel Brown    1
Mark Zhulin 1
```

I now want to modify it so the query would only show the rows where the staff supervises the most students including multiple staff members e.g if two staff had 3 students they would both show

I thought I would be able to do it through a HAVING clause of

```
 HAVING ((COUNT(FACULTY.F_FIRST || ' ' || F_LAST))) 
= MAX(COUNT(FACULTY.F_FIRST || ' ' || F_LAST))
```

but this tells me i have a invalid relational operator in it.I believe the first part of the have clause is correct since i can use it to find specific row values but not the maximum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `DENSE_RANK()` or `RANK()`.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT (f.F_FIRST || ' ' || f.F_LAST) AS STAFF, CNT as STUDENTCOUNT
FROM FACULTY f INNER JOIN
     (SELECT s.F_ID, COUNT(*) as CNT,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM STUDENT s
      GROUP BY s.F_ID
     ) s
     ON s.F_ID = f.F_ID
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This formulation assumes that the first/last name is unique for a given `F_ID`.

Also, note that the query is easier to write and to read when you use table aliases.

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I run the whole thing it tells me its not a single-group group function.

Comment: To change this I simply changed "COUNT(*) as STUDENTCOUNT" TO  CNT and it worked